# How to write nested dictionary in csv with python when the row contents are key values of related key (the header of each column)?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary called *"output"*, there are some other dictionary nested in it as bellow:

```
>>> output.keys() 
dict_keys(['posts', 'totalResults', 'moreResultsAvailable', 'next', 'requestsLeft', 'warnings'])

>>> output['posts'][0].keys() 
dict_keys(['thread', 'uuid', 'url', 'ord_in_thread', 'parent_url', 'author', 'published', 'title','text', 'highlightText', 'highlightTitle', 'highlightThreadTitle', 'language', 'external_links', 'external_images', 'entities', 'rating', 'crawled', 'updated'])

>>> output['posts'][0]['thread'].keys() 
dict_keys(['uuid', 'url', 'site_full', 'site', 'site_section', 'site_categories', 'section_title', 'title', 'title_full', 'published', 'replies_count', 'participants_count', 'site_type', 'country', 'spam_score', 'main_image', 'performance_score', 'domain_rank', 'reach', 'social'])

>>> output['posts'][0]['thread']['social'].keys() 
dict_keys(['facebook', 'gplus', 'pinterest', 'linkedin', 'stumbledupon', 'vk'])
```

I want to make a csv file consisting of a list of selected keys from **output['posts'][0]**, **output['posts'][0]['thread']** and **output['posts'][0]['thread']['social']** with related values as each row content, I came up with this code:

```
post_keys = output['posts'][0].keys()
post_thread_keys = output['posts'][0]['thread'].keys()
social_keys = output['posts'][0]['thread']['social'].keys()

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=post_thread_keys)
    writer.writeheader()

    for i in range(len(output['posts'])):
         for key in output['posts'][i]['thread']:
            writer.writerow(output['posts'][i]['thread'])
```

It only works for first level of dictionary which is *"output['posts'][0]['thread']"*, not other insiders, and also it doubles the number of rows which is 200 now instead of 100.

Now the result is like this:
[image: current output]

Wish to be like this:
[image: required output]

Please have a look at the output file I have stored on google drive for more tangible approach:
[file.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16p-f0Z1HQPIl6hX7AvDrp8Otvu4fF4r1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Include an abridged sample of your dictionary to get better answers.

Comment: Also please include a sample of your expected output.

Comment: I have added the result and desired image of the current output.

Comment: Are you able to do `print(output)` and give us a link to what the output is? You could use something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I put an output file on drive, please have a look.

Comment: Hi Farhad, to be able to run your script we would need create your `output` dictionary variable. To do this you would need to give us an example in text form. We would then be able to create `file.csv` by running the script.

Comment: I share the exact code I have used to generate that dictionary, it contains the token I use to collect data from that python library and is limited for use. I hope this can help:
https://pastebin.com/7TXX5wV3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function to create the sub-keys in the format you have specified. By using a function, it can also be called to give you the list of the extra column
names needed for the header.

As you are adding 3 sub-entries, they could be removed from the columns to avoid duplication (by using `.pop()`)

```
import webhoseio
import csv

def get_social_entries(social):
    social_entries = {}

    for social_key, social_values in social.items():
        for key, value in social_values.items():
            social_entries[f'{social_key}_{key}'] = value
            
    return social_entries
        
    
    
# <<Get output here>>

csv_columns = []
 
first_post = output['posts'][0]

for key in first_post['thread']:
    csv_columns.append(key)
 
for key in first_post:
    if key not in ['entities', 'thread', 'social']:
        csv_columns.append(key)
 
for key in first_post['entities']:
    csv_columns.append(key)

csv_columns.extend(list(get_social_entries(first_post['thread']['social']).keys()))

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    
    for post in output['posts']:
        thread = post.pop('thread')
        entities = post.pop('entities')
        social = thread.pop('social')
        social_entries = get_social_entries(social)
        writer.writerow(post | thread | entities | social_entries)     # | operator needs Python 3.9
```

This assumes you are using Python 3.9, if not you could use something like:

```
row = post
row.update(thread)
row.update(entities)
row.update(social_entries)
writer.writerow(row)
```

Note: `newline=''` is added to remove the extra blank lines in the output.

You could use a similar approach to also expand the `entities`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind contribution, just please have a look at the generated csv file, there are 6 rows extra, and their filled columns exceeded far longer, for me they are rows number 17,18,24,25,86 and 87.

Comment: This is the link to that csv file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BCVyW41H0Fbt9z7WKMKaGoka1HTOJUF1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the file looks fine. CSV files don't specify a width for a column. The `text` column is sometimes very wide and sometimes many lines long. If this is a problem you could modify it before writing. e.g. convert newlines to spaces. If you are using Excel to view it, make sure you start with a blank spreadsheet and use Data->From Text/CSV to import it using utf-8 encoding (don't double click on the file)

Comment: Yes you are right, it was my ms office problem to open it with flaws. The code works pretty well. I do appreciate your precious help and the time you spent on it. Thank you very much!